# Webkit Extra Space at the top of the 'body' element when setting a margin-top on a descendant element

Tags: html, css, webkit

I was playing around with making my page occupy the full viewport with this basic

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

but I noticed that when I added a block element with a margin, the page sizing was off by the amount of the margin.  To demonstrate, try this html in a webkit browser:

```html
<html style="height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
  <body style="min-height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <h1 style="margin-top: 100px;">Box Sizing</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

You will notice that the body always overflows the html element, causing it to scroll.  Does anybody know why this is overflowing?

Comment: why do you have a height on `html`?

Answer (score 1):

This is known as [collapsing margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins). The vertical margin on the `h1` element is collapsing with the `body` element, which causes the adjoining margins to combime and form a single margin, thereby resulting in the `body` element being shifted down (as though it has a `margin-top` of `100px`.

According to section [8.3.1 of the relevant spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins), the following rule(s) prevent the margins from collapsing:

> Margins of `inline-block` boxes do not collapse (not even with their in-flow children).

Therefore you could simply set the `display` of the element to `inline-block` and then add `width: 100%`. You could also float the element as well:

> Margins between a floated box and any other box do not collapse (not even between a float and its in-flow children).

In the updated example below, I simply set the `display` of the `h1` element to `inline-block` so that the margins no longer collapse.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
h1 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Box Sizing</h1>
```

See the spec I linked to for a more detailed explanation along with additional workarounds and rules that prevent the margins from collapsing.